# Names of Softwares used for modeling

Tags: computer-networks

Which tools or softwares are mostly used for the purpose of modeling a computer network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean simulating computer networks? because modelling is different (you can model your network as a graph for instance). If this is the case have a look at these simulators:

- *NS2*: built with C++, a discrete-event simulator, open source, and perhaps the most useful. You would need to use Tcl to write the script of the simulation experiments. New open source libraries are always added. I suggest it, however, i know many consider it a bet complex. Good knowledge in C++ is required if you want to maximally exploit it (at least to print your statistics and analyze them). The newer version is *NS3* (i have nt used it yet), but from what I read, you can write your simulation experiments using python or c++.
- *Opnet*: I am not a fan, and it is not open-source. I think there is a student-version.
- *simjava*: if you are a java person, then use this. (I haven't used it, but i saw it being cited in many research papers).

but be careful before starting working with any "network simulator" because in many cases you don't need complex simulators. A simple C++, Java or Python code would be sufficient. (Actually, it is always a good programming exercise to create your own discrete-event simulator for a network).

If you are interested in distributed processors simulation (from a theoretical point of view), then I would suggest *erlang (a programming language)*. It is functional language very similar to Haskell (created by Eriksson). it is very easy to create processes with identities. But even more, you can let the processors exchange messages by sending/receiving messages in a very simple way.

Comment: You might want to add NS3 along with NS2 too, as it may possibly be easier to use for educational purposes.

Comment: @Paresh I added it.